# How to reset the "Maint Reqd" light in a 2015 Toyota Rav4?

Tags: toyota, scheduled-maintenance

I just changed the oil on my girlfriend's 2015 Toyota Rav4 LE.

The "maintenance required" light is lit up on the dash.  It turns on 5000 miles after the last time it was reset. I want to reset it so that if there is ever a warranty claim, the computer will say she maintained the car well.

#### How do I reset the `Maint Reqd` light in a Toyota?

Comment: Oil change side notes (for other's reference): It is the exact same engine and manual for all three trim levels: LE, XLE, and Limited. I used 0W-20 which is recommended in the manual.  I used a full synthetic oil even though that was not specified in the manual.

Answer (score 3):

The idiot's (me!) guide to turning off the `Maint Reqd` light:

1. Start the car.

   - Turn the key to the `Start` position.
   - The engine should be starting.
   - Release the key so it springs back to the `On` position.
   - Do you hear the engine? (You should.)
2. Hit the `Disp` button until `Trip A` is shown on the odometer's LCD screen.
3. Turn the car off.

   - Are you able to remove the key? (You should be able to.)
4. Press and hold the `Disp` button with your left hand.

   - You are going to continue holding that for the next few steps.
5. Continue holding `Disp` while you...

## Turn the key to `On`, not `Start`!

6. Do you hear the engine? (You should ***not***.)
7. Continue holding `Disp` while the odometer's LCD screen blinks:

   - `------`,
   - `-----`,
   - `----`,
   - `---`,
   - `--`,
   - `-`,
   - `000000`
8. You can stop pressing the `Disp` button.
9. Turn the key to `Off`.
10. *Start* the car.
11. `Maint Reqd` is not lit up!

Comment: This procedure didn't work. Maintenance Light is still on. All fluids and filters are fine. Only thing I can think of is that it came on a little while after I hit 36,000 miles. (I took it in to the shop at 35,400 so thry could do any work that might fall under the warranty before it ran out. All was A+.

Comment: Just used this on my 2015 RAV4. Works perfectly!!! Thank you!!!!